# When adding fields to a next version of the SQLite DB in Android, should I include them in the table definition AND the ALTER statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a USER table in my android app which is released in App Store

but then I had to add a POSTCODE field and release a new version of the app with the Database version set to 2 now.

So in the app when I create my DatabaseManager object, upon its creation I first call

```
public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, Preferences.LOCAL_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableUserCreate);
    // Remainder omitted for clarity
}
```

and then in the onUpgdade I do the following:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    switch (version_old) {
    case 1:
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
    break;
    }
```

Now I have two queries:

```
SQLQueries.tableUserCreate;
SQLQueries.addPostcodeFieldToUserTable;
```

My question is: Should I add the POSTCODE field in the "CREATE TABLE "tableUserCreate" query and then put it in the ALTER TABLE statement "addPostcodeFieldToUserTable" or should I ONLY put it in the ALTER TABLE statement "addPostcodeFieldToUserTable"?

The problem is I already put it in both the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements and now I have already released a version 3 of the app - has the POSTCODE field been added twice to the table? What if in version 4 I remove the POSTCODE field declaration from the CREATE TABLE query and only leave it in the ALTER TABLE query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I add the POSTCODE field in the "CREATE TABLE "tableUserCreate" query and then put it in the ALTER TABLE statement "addPostcodeFieldToUserTable"

Yes.

> or should I ONLY put it in the ALTER TABLE statement "addPostcodeFieldToUserTable"?

No.

> The problem is I already put it in both the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements and now I have already released a version 3 of the app - has the POSTCODE field been added twice to the table?

No. `onCreate()` is only called when the database file didn't exist. After it completes, you already have a database with the requested version number and `onUpgrade()` is not called.

`onUpgrade()` is called when a database file already exists and its version number is smaller than what you requested. `onCreate()` is not called.

Answer (score 2):

`onCreate` is called when your app is newly installed (or when the user deleted your app's data), so the CREATE TABLE in there must have the new column(s).

`onUpgrade` is called when your app is run the first time with the database of an older version.
If you don't care about the old data, you can delete everything and then just call `onCreate`, but if you want to keep the old data, you must upgrade the database, so you need the ALTER TABLE.